# Python: how to read text file then count specific word and print date,time from another line when found specific word

Tags: python, text

how to read text file then count specific word and print date,time from another line when found specific word

for example text file

```
2023-09-15T16:55:10Z word word
word word
word **specific word** word word
word word 
word word
2023-09-15T16:56:20Z word word
word word
word word
word word
2023-09-15T16:57:30Z word word
word word
word **specific word** word word
```

Result i want

```
Number of occurrences of the word : 2
2023-09-15T16:55:10
2023-09-15T16:57:30
```

Now my code can count number but print all line

```
f = open('file_name.txt', 'r')
occurrences = data.count("specific word")
print('Number of occurrences of the word :', occurrences)
for line in f:
    f = line[:19]
    print(f)
```

and result look like this:

```
Number of occurrences of the word : 2
2023-09-15T16:55:10
word word
word **specific word**
word word

word word
word word

2023-09-15T16:56:20
word word
word word

2023-09-15T16:57:30
word word
word **specific word**
```

thank so much

Comment: What is `data` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to produce your desired result is to use regular expressions.

First, we split your text into chunks whenever a date is found.

Next, we search through the list of chunks for text matching ***specific word***. When it is found, we record the preceding date.

```
import re

with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

re_date = r'(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}Z)'

txt_split = re.split(re_date, txt)

results = []
for i, t in enumerate(txt_split):
    if re.search(r'\*\*specific word\*\*', t) and i > 0:
        results.append(txt_split[i-1])

print(f'Number of occurrences of the word : {len(results)}')
print('\n'.join(results))
```

The above code produces the desired result:

```
Number of occurrences of the word : 2
2023-09-15T16:55:10Z
2023-09-15T16:57:30Z
```

##### Appendix

In this example, I used an oversimplified regex expression to find a date in *yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ* format. In production, you may want to ensure that it begins with digits *19* or *20* and ensure that months and days are limited to *01-12* and *01-31*, respectively, and there may be additional constraints.